# Is there a way to have a two step conditional formatting in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I need to is a way to make a formula or use conditional formatting to achieve following.If cell A=1 and cell B>1 at the same time, then cell C turns red. Is it possible?

Tried using the "custom formula" feature in conditional formatting, but it does not allow to use more than value to use as a condition.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

***Apply to range***: `C:C`

***Custom formula is***:

```js
=(A1=1)*(B1>1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make so that the rule works for the entire column. i.e if A3=1 and B3>1 then C3 turns red?

Comment: the given formula works for the whole column C provided you have give the range setting as `C:C` (as in screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

The formating that usually works for me when doing conditional formating is =AND($A1=1,$B1>1)